# Cross browser Modal window

Tags: asp.net

I came across a requirement where modal window needs to be displayed to users visiting from browsers like IE, Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera. I used the **ShowModalDialog** function which didn't work across the above listed browsers.

While searching I came to see jQuery plugin which displays modal window, but only accepts text and not URLs. My requirement is to set an ASPX page URL to the modal window.

Can someone please help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 3):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions that might fit your req.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512257/jquery-modal-boxes-and-iframe