# How do I setup a popup form page?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Modal Boxes and Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512257/jquery-modal-boxes-and-iframe)

I have **2 aspx** pages

**1. Summary.aspx**

**2 Update.ascx**

The above both pages works fine. I have a **link** on the summary page that goes to the **update.ascx** page.

How do I setup my code to make update.ascx popup with the unclickable summary page in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to render update.aspx in an iframe. Then display the iframe in a modal div along with another div to block the background page.

If you're using jQuery, there are plenty of plugins which will do all the groundwork for you and will also have greater browser compatibility.

Fancybox is one such plugin: http://fancybox.net/home

Answer (score 0):

using jquery and [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), maybe something like

```
<div id="popup">loading...</div>
<a id="popup_link">show popup</a>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#popup_link").bind("click", function(){
            $("#popup").load("update.aspx").dialog({modal:true});
        });
    });
</script>
```