# Display content from url inside jquery simplemodal

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I want to load this content https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside in to jquery simplemodal dialog.

How can i do that?

**UPDATE**

I've tried this sample:

```
$('#paypal-popup').click(function (e) {
            var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";
            $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
                closeHTML: "",
                containerCss: {
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    borderColor: "#fff",
                    height: 450,
                    padding: 0,
                    width: 830
                },
                overlayClose: true
            });
        });
```

and it is working for me, but if i change src url to https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside it is redirecting me there.

How may i fix that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512257/jquery-modal-boxes-and-iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever library you use, **you cannot load the content of that url in an iframe**.
It **will surely get re-directed** because there is a small script running in it.

If you **view source on that page** you can see this.

```
<style type="text/css" id="antiClickjack">
    body{display:none !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (self === top) {
        var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
        antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
    } 
    else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
</script>
```

This means **if the page is in an iframe, hide contents and change the pages location to iframe's location**.
Its there to prevent [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)

If you want to display any other sites in an iframe, just use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/C6rR2/1/

Comment: try that src https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside it will redirect there

Comment: what do you think if i copy that content in to local file and than load it? but the only issue i can see is that if the content on that url will change i won't know that.

Comment: you can do that. but change of content might be a problem :)

Comment: I think i could live with that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jquery Plug-in in your code

see~

http://fancybox.net/

or

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/